# Integration/calculus additional IGCSE maths problem

Tags: calculus

Hi I am having another problem with additional maths IGCSE (and no teacher to help at the moment). I can figure out the first part the second part I am struggling with..
[image]

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Hint: for the first part you were given a function $f(x)$ and were asked to find $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$. Let us call this answer as $G(x)$. For the second part you are given $\int [x+2G(x)] \, dx$. This can be written as $$\int x \, dx + 2 \int G(x) \, dx.$$ Now ask yourself what is $\int G(x) \, dx$.

Answer (score 2):

The derivative is

$$\color{red}{4x^3\sqrt{\sin(x)}+x^4\frac{\cos(x)}{2\sqrt{\sin(x)}}}$$

for the antiderivative,

$$\int x+2\Bigl(\color{red}{4x^3\sqrt{\sin(x)}+x^4\frac{\cos(x)}{2\sqrt{\sin(x)}}}\Bigr)dx=$$

$$\frac{x^2}{2}+2x^4\sqrt{\sin(x)}+C$$

Comment: very useful thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Please, could nobody ask me to use Maths Jax on this question? I am just trying to help this pupil.
[image]

Comment: No. Take a few minutes to learn mathjax, it isn't that hard. Put \$ around the maths and use _ for indexes ^ for exponents \frac{}{} for fractions and \int for integrals.

Comment: thanks so much helped a lot

Comment: You're welcome, always happy to share my knowledge :)